# Finding area bounded by 3 function that aren't constant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find an area that are bounded by $3$ functions:
\begin{align}
 &=  + 6
,\\
 &= ^3
,\\
2 +  &= 0
.
\end{align}

I only found the solution if one of the functions is constant, like $x=2$.

Comment: What's goes wrong? You should have$$\int_{-4}^0(x+6)-(-x/2)\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^2(x+6)-x^3\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @Dhipa some vizualization may help ([wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dx%2B6%2C+y%3Dx%5E3%2C+2y%2Bx%3D0))

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bkmwhmc8ki

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. For future reference, you may take a look at 
[this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to see how to format math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=x+6
,\\
f_2(x)&=x^3
,\\
f_3(x)&=-x/2
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
S_{ABC}
&=S_{ABD}+S_{BCD}
\\
&=
\int_{-4}^0 f_1(x)-f_3(x) \, dx
+
\int_0^2 f_1(x)-f_2(x) \, dx
=12+10=22
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This is what the graphs look like:
[image]

The first step is to find the intersection points of the different graphs.
The intersection point of $y=x+6$ and $y=-\frac{x}{2}$ is $(-4,2)$.
The intersection point of $y=x+6$ and $y=x^3$ is $(2,8)$.
The intersection point of $y=x^3$ and $-\frac{x}{2}$ is $(0,0)$.

The area enclosed by the curves is equal to 
$$\int_{-4}^2(x+6) dx -\int_{0}^2(x^3) dx -\int_{-4}^0(-\frac{x}{2}) dx$$
which $=30-4-4=22$ That should be your answer. I hope that helped!